# How to set loading gif on dynamic binding of background image into div in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one bootstrap modal. I am binding dynamic back-ground image in div. Here is bootstrap modal

```
<div id="ImageTagModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div id="jobImage" class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript code.

```
function image(src)
    {
        $('#jobImage').css("background-image", "url("+src+")");  
        $('#jobImage').css("background-size", "cover"); 
        $('#ImageTagModal').modal();   
    }
```

Now my images size will be in MB so when i load bootstrap modal it takes too much time for loading background image into div. So i want to set loading gif till background image loaded into div. As image is loaded in background of div, gif will stop. How to handle this scenario in bootstrap modal?

Comment: create a demo if possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm right its server response time for image, for that you can wait till server response/ajax call completion, display another modal of spinner/loading and disable background then after response when DOM is ready, you can show actual modal.

for more share actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Here i got solution.

```
function image(src)
    {
        $('#loader').show(); //This is my gif image

        $('<img/>').attr('src', src).load(function() {
            $('#jobImage').css("background-image", "url("+src+")");  
            $('#jobImage').css("background-size", "cover"); 
            $('#ImageTagModal').modal();  
            $('#loader').hide(); 
        }); 
    }
```